# Does Adolf Hitler have a counterpart in Fullmetal Alchemist 2003's Amestris?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-2003

in the 2003 anime of *Fullmetal Alchemist* we see that our world have counterparts to characters in Amestris. in the *Conqueror of Shamballa* film we see

- Officer Hughes (Maes Hughes's Counterpart)
- Gracia the Florist (Gracia Hughes's counterpart)
- Alfons Heiderich (Alphonse Elric's Counterpart)
- Noah (Rose Thomas's Counterpart)
- Fritz Lang (King Bradley's Counterpart)
- Erik Jan Hanussen (Frank Archer's Counterpart)
- unnamed waitress who looks like Lyra
- unnamed truck driver who looks like Scar
- unnamed passenger with ^ who looks like Lust

[image: Scar and Lust counterparts with Noah]

[image: Lyra's counterpart]

and we know that before the movie there was a counterpart of Ed who Ed took over the body of when Dante sent him through The Gate

I've been wondering that since a lot of people we know in Amestris has counterparts in Our World, does Adolf Hitler have a counterpart in Amestris? particularly the 2003 anime series

Comment: Here is an article on [Adolf Hitler's role in the Conquerer of Shamballa movie](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Adolf_Hitler_(Fullmetal_Alchemist)) on the Villainn Wiki. It does not directly answer the question, but it goes to show that the notion is not too far fetched since Hitler exists in this depiction of Germany (some shows tend to ignore him), and might give people clues to help find an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think its Roy Mustang, he wants to be the Führer, and turn Amestris in a "Democracy", but we dont know what is a democracy to Amestrians and what kind of Democracy is it. It can be a "Aristocratic Authoritarian Democracy" like one of Gottfried Feder´s (creator of the National Socialism and the first economist of the Reich, a genius) possible State system planned to Germany, that Would exist an One Party Parliament, and the Candidates for Führer would be selected for capacity and competence (technical evaluation), and the people would vote for the best candidate, and the chosen one would turn into Führer of Germany. Thats an advanced mode of democracy in my vision, and it can be one of the possibilities of "Roy Mustang´s Democracy".
Ok thats only a theory (and a mad one XD), but would be interesthing XD
I know the age of Mustantg and Hitler are not the same, but Some characters dont have the same age, so... whatever, thank you for reading.